# How can I run a python script in ubuntu background?

Tags: python, linux

How can I run a python script in ubuntu background? I tried to use '&', for example:

> python3 test.py &

but when I close the terminal, this process seems to be closed as well because I can't get any update logs from this test script any more.

Comment: Add `nohup` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784462/how-to-run-multiple-php-scripts-in-background-on-ubuntu

Comment: read this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setsid. In your case by running:

```
setsid python test.py
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, you can use nohup.

```
nohup python test.py
```

You can see the difference between them in this answer: [What's the difference between nohup and a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958249/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-a-daemon)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `nohup` command as Serge mentioned.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh) looks like what you want

Comment: Thanks very much.